# Can we get the slots in a string related to formatting?

Tags: ruby, string

I'm interested in getting the list of slots in a string related to formatting by the operator `%`. Supposing I have a `slots` method for that, it would do the following:

```ruby
t = '... %{s1} ... %{s2} ... %{s3} ...'
t.slots # => ['s1', 's2', 's3']
```

1. Is there such a method as the hypothetical `slots`?
2. Is there a way to get these slots **WITHOUT using regular expression**, but using the same parsing routine as the one used by the Ruby engine?
3. Is there a library that implements something like the formatting interpolation that exposes a method analogous to the mentioned `slots`?
4. If there is not any other option, how could I produce a descent parser (not regular expression) for this case?

I read [what I think is the source code of `%`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/96db72ce38b27799dd8e80ca00696e41234db6ba/sprintf.c#L631), and I'm afraid string formatting has no evident separation for slots detection.

Comment: That's my first time looking at `rb_str_format`... yikes.

Comment: Ugh. I had an answer written for `"#{abc}"`, and just now I notice... That's not what you want at all.

Comment: @Ven what would that be anyways?

Comment: @jgomo3 Answered both for good mesure...

Comment: I'm very curious what the use-case is for this...

Comment: Interpolating a Template with a Hash, which could produce another template which could be interpolated with the same hash. I have to guard against Circular References.

The actual Use case is a Hash of FilePaths you can "name", and also reference.

paths = {base: '/tmp', p1: '%{base}/p1', p1_1: '%{p1}/_1', p2: '%{base}/p2'}; explode(paths, :p1_1) # --> produces '/tmp/p1/_1'

I don't allow Circular references.

Currently I'm using regexps. I would prefer to use the same algorithm as `%`.

Comment: @Max Here is the snippet of my code that is doing that https://gist.github.com/jgomo3/ac5d4d3a828c20b4b4daee84b206670e

Comment: @Max so the Use cases for my question are actually 1) The way I'm protecting the code against circular references (recording the slots being expanded while processing the string to check if already expanded), and 2) to check if there is still slots to be processed as the stop condition.

Comment: @jgomo3 see, I would solve that much simpler: the longest reference chain would be the number of keys in the hash so do that many replacements+1. If the last replacement changes the string you must have a circular reference

Comment: @Max not necessarily. You could repeat one reference many times. Even in different nested levels. In fact, my implementation is erroneous also. I.E: {o: "%{a} .. %{a} .. %{b}", a: '#', b: "%{a} .. %{a}"} Has no circular references.

The fixed version for checking that, would still use a record of the slots.

Comment: @jgomo3 The number of references in each string is irrelevant since string substitution replaces all of them at once. Your example has three keys and after three replacements it is fully expanded. The fourth replacement has no effect i.e. no circular references.

Comment: @Max You are right!. I'll fix that immediately. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

At least, you can do this:

```
t = '... %{s1} ... %{s2} ... %{s3} ...'

h = {}
begin
  t % h
rescue KeyError => e
  h[e.key] = true
  retry
end
h.keys # => [:s1, :s2, :s3]
```

Comment: Encapsulated, it is perfect!

Comment: Although I get this error:

undefined method `key' for #<KeyError: key not found: :s1>. I don't find a Ruby version where the KeyError object has the method key.

Comment: I assume the newest version of Ruby unless specified otherwise. https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/KeyError.html#method-i-key